# LG G4 Bootloop--how do I get my pictures back?

Tags: boot-loop, data-recovery, google-drive, lg-g4

My LG G4 just recently went into the dreaded bootloop. I plan on sending it to LG to fix, but my pictures from earlier in the year are on the phone's memory. I also have a ton of music on it, but my pictures are more important to me. I checked in my Google Drive account, and it had automatically backed up on April 11, 2017. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out if or how to view or obtain the backed up information? Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **Google Drive does not backup your photos directly from your Gallery**. It only backups data, like user settings and probably cache, from your various apps. Next time, if you want to backup your photos and videos, use [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com/) which would have eliminated this issue.

It seems that accessing your (and my) phone's backup is not possible through the web version of Google Drive. It is however possible, in the Android version, to see the size of the data being saved and by what app.